# Jenkins - Keeper Vault Integration into Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, credentials, secret-manager

Getting issue in fetching credentials from keeper while running the pipeline - job running for long time.

--

- already added one-time key to jenkins credentials
- script used here :
  "

```
def COLOR_MAP = [
    'SUCCESS': 'good',
    'FAILURE': 'danger',
    'ABORTED': 'yellow'
    ]

pipeline {
    agent { label 'WindowsAgent' } 

    // environment {
    //     application = '########'
    // }
    options {
        durabilityHint 'PERFORMANCE_OPTIMIZED'
        buildDiscarder logRotator(
            artifactDaysToKeepStr: '',
            artifactNumToKeepStr: '',
            daysToKeepStr: '',
            numToKeepStr: '15')
    }
    stages {
        stage('keeper') {
            steps {
                withKsm(application: [
                    [credentialsId: 'fb37d668-a609-491b-ab5-63f3d54eac', 
                    secrets: [
                        [destination: 'env', envVar: 'logn', filePath: '', notation: 'keeper://FNi6yH-RM1zibqsgHIRV7Q/field/login'],
                        [destination: 'env', envVar: 'passwd', filePath: '', notation: 'keeper://FNi6yH-RM1zibqsgHIRV7Q/field/password']
                        
                    ]
                ]
                ]) {
                        // print('success')
                        // some block
                        sh'''
                                    # Will be redacted in console  
                                    echo "login = ${logn}"
                                    echo "password = ${passwd}"
                                '''
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-- any suggestions to overcome the issue and fetch credentials from keeper vault
NOTE : able to fetch cred on keeper secret manager from local - maybe changes required in jenkins config or in script. & Jenkins is in Linux env

Integrating Jenkins pipeline with the keeper vault - for credentials